# Cassandra query for multiple table

Tags: cassandra

Hi i have a dataset contains airline dataset.

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/sherrytp/airline-delay-analysis/code

There are few csv file categorized by year.

As I want to query the highest frequency of carrier, I need to go through every single year, that mean every single csv file. I am aware that Cassandra does not support query of multiple tables, so I am stuck at here.

May I have an idea how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like all files are formatted in the same way. Why not put every CSV in the same single table and use the YEAR as the partition key to implementing queries per year? Partition might be a bit big but it would work.

To load the Data use DSBulk.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.